# displaying xml simple in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have spent about 6-7 hours trying to get a basic xml page to display just readable at least using xsl, and cannot get my head around it. Is it that hard? Or am I just struggling big time.

My xml code is basic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="recipepages.xsl"?><!DOCTYPE chefmaster [
<!ELEMENT chefmaster (recipe+)>
  <!ELEMENT recipe (title, dishtype?, dishcategory?, chef, countryshown, episodeshown?, preparationtime, cookingtime, serves, caloriesperserve?, allergenslist?, ingredients, method, recommendedbeverage?, author*, mainingredientlink+)>
  <!ATTLIST recipe cuisine (chinese|french|greek|indian|italian|japanese|mexican|notspecified|thai|western) #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT dishtype (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT dishcategory (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT chef (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT countryshown (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT episodeshown (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT preparationtime (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT cookingtime (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT serves (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT caloriesperserve (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT allergenslist (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT ingredients (main, ingredient+)>
  <!ELEMENT main (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST main image CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT ingredient (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST ingredient amount CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST ingredient units CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ELEMENT method (step+)>
  <!ELEMENT step (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT recommendedbeverage (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT author (givenname, surname)>
  <!ELEMENT givenname (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT mainingredientlink (#PCDATA)>
]>
<chefmaster>
   <recipe cuisine="notspecified">
    <title>Quick carrot and coriander soup</title>
    <dishtype>Entree</dishtype>
    <dishcategory>Vegetarian</dishcategory>
    <chef>Alison Good</chef>
    <countryshown>Australia</countryshown>
    <episodeshown>Season 2, Episode 1</episodeshown>
    <preparationtime>5 mins</preparationtime>
    <cookingtime>15 mins</cookingtime>
    <serves>6</serves>
    <caloriesperserve>85</caloriesperserve>
    <allergenslist>None</allergenslist>
    <ingredients>
      <main image="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XaAgu2H_RDk/TmxXBKiOJ8I/AAAAAAAABQg/DrMxd41-b8s/s1600/carrot.jpg">Carrot</main>
      <ingredient amount="4">Large carrots, peeled and cut into large chunks</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1" units="tablespoon">Olive oil</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1/4">Large onion, diced</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="4" units="cups">Vegetable stock</ingredient>
      <ingredient>Large bunch of fresh coriander, de-stemmed and roughly chopped</ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <method>
      <step>1. Heat the oil in a large saucepan over medium heat and saute the carrots and onion for a few minutes until the onion has softened a little.</step>
      <step>2. Pour in the vegetable stock and add the coriander. Bring to a boil and cook until the carrots are tender; about 10 minutes. Remove from the heat and allow to cool slightly.</step>
      <step>3. Puree the soup until smooth using a hand-blender or food processor. Reheat before serving if necessary.</step>
    </method>
    <recommendedbeverage>Water</recommendedbeverage>
    <author>
      <givenname>Sarah</givenname>
      <surname>May</surname>
    </author>
    <mainingredientlink>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot</mainingredientlink>
   </recipe>
   <recipe cuisine="greek">
    <title>Prawns (garides) saganaki</title>
    <dishtype>Entree</dishtype>
    <chef>Alison Good</chef>
    <countryshown>Australia</countryshown>
    <episodeshown>Season 2, Episode 3</episodeshown>
    <preparationtime>5 mins</preparationtime>
    <cookingtime>35 mins</cookingtime>
    <serves>4</serves>
    <caloriesperserve>287</caloriesperserve>
    <allergenslist>Seafood</allergenslist>
    <ingredients>
      <main image="http://images.wikia.com/prawnhub/images/d/df/Going_to_be_a_Fairy_Prawn.jpg">Prawns</main>
      <ingredient amount="500" units="grams">Raw king prawns</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="3" units="tablespoons">Olive oil</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1">Onion, chopped</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1" units="teaspoon">Freshly chopped parsley</ingredient>
      <ingredient>Large bunch of fresh coriander, de-stemmed and roughly chopped</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1" units="cup">White wine</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="400" units="gram">Tin chopped tomatoes, drained</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1" units="clove">Garlic, finely chopped</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="200" units="grams">Feta cheese, cubed</ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <method>
      <step>1. Place the prawns in a pot and add enough water to cover them. Boil for 5 minutes, then drain, reserving the liquid and set aside.</step>
      <step>2. Heat about 2 tablespoons of oil in a saucepan. Add the onion and cook and stir until the onions are soft. Mix in the parsley, wine, tomatoes, garlic and remaining olive oil.</step>
      <step>3. Simmer, stirring occasionally, for about 30 minutes, or until the sauce is thickened.</step>
      <step>4. While the sauce is simmering, the prawns should have become cool enough to handle. First remove the legs by pinching them, and then pull off the shells, leaving the head and tail on.</step>
      <step>5. When the sauce has thickened, stir in the prawns. Bring to a simmer, and cook for about 5 minutes.</step>
      <step>6. Add the feta cheese and remove from the heat. Let stand until the cheese starts to melt. Serve warm.</step>
    </method>
    <author>
      <givenname>George</givenname>
      <surname>Adams</surname>
    </author>
    <author>
      <givenname>Alex</givenname>
      <surname>Antonovich</surname>
    </author>
    <mainingredientlink>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrimp_meat</mainingredientlink>
   </recipe>
   <recipe cuisine="greek">
    <title>Spicy Baked Feta</title>
    <dishtype>Entree</dishtype>
    <dishcategory>Vegetarian</dishcategory>
    <chef>Neil Perry</chef>
    <countryshown>Australia</countryshown>
    <episodeshown>Season 2, Episode 3</episodeshown>
    <preparationtime>3 mins</preparationtime>
    <cookingtime>10 mins</cookingtime>
    <serves>4</serves>
    <caloriesperserve>267</caloriesperserve>
    <allergenslist>Chilli</allergenslist>
    <ingredients>
      <main image="http://www.gaganisbros.com.au/images/Greek_Feta_Texture.jpg">Feta Cheese</main>
      <ingredient amount="250" units="gram">Slab of feta cheese</ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="3 to 4" units="tablespoons">Chilli flakes</ingredient>
      <ingredient units="pinch">Oregano</ingredient>
      <ingredient>Olive oil</ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <method>
      <step>1. Preheat oven 150 degrees C.</step>
      <step>2. Place feta in small baking dish. Drizzle with olive oil. Cover liberally with chili flakes, and a sprinkle of oregano.</step>
      <step>3. Bake uncovered for 10 minutes until feta is soft.</step>
      <step>4. Serve with crusty bread or toast.</step>
    </method>
    <recommendedbeverage>Glass of shiraz</recommendedbeverage>
    <author>
      <givenname>Christina</givenname>
      <surname>Motso</surname>
    </author>
    <mainingredientlink>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feta</mainingredientlink>
    <mainingredientlink>http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/glossary/g/Feta.htm</mainingredientlink>
   </recipe>
</chefmaster>
```

Is it possible to display it in order so that the recipes can be read easily in a few basic lines in an xsl doc?

Comment: You'd need to include how you actually want it to display. It's fairly easy, although if yu're not used to declarative or (sort-of) functional programming, it'll seem a little foreign at first.

Comment: Please, provide the exact wanted output and any rules that you want the transformation to implement (obey).

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a quick-and-dirty rendition into HTML using a few generic rules, and then customize it by adding more rules to make it prettier. Here's a starter, which displays elements and attributes based on their depth in the document; it's not beautiful, but it's a starting point:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body><xsl:apply-templates/></body></html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*">
  <h1>
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </h1>  
   <table>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*/*">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/*/*/*">
  <dt>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </dt>
  <dd><xsl:value-of select="."/></dd>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), ': ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```